# How to import a site in my localhost

Tags: joomla-3.x, localhost, backups

I have a joomla 2.5 site, and I want to upgrade it to joomla 3.x, but before I want to import my joola 2.5 site on my local server (wamp) to make some modifications (change the template and other stuff...) 
Where I am now :

- I saved my site's files with Filezilla, and put the file in my www file in wamp.
- I saved my database from the server.
- I have downloaded the latest version of joomla, and put the file in the www file too.
- I created a new database with phpMyAdmin, and import my database previously saved into it.
- I have installed this joomla on my wamp localhost and specify the database I created previously.

Now, of course, the joomla site i got is empty, and i want to retrive my site with the files I saved with filezilla and here I don't know how to do that.
Or, and it's quite possible, I really don't understand how import my joomla site in my local server and all the things above are wrong...

Thank you

Comment: I think you'd be best off using Akeeba Backup to transfer the site to your localhost

Comment: @Lodder I know but the problem is that i'm not the true admin of this site and I have no right to install new plug-in ... So I wanted to do otherwise

Comment: If you have no rights to install extensions - then what right have you got to download the site using FTP and make modifications. Sounds very dodgy to me!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need to download the latest version of Joomla, because the files you download from your original site already has everything you need.

Akeeba Backup is a better way to move/restore a site, but as you say you don't have full admin access, it's not an option. You'll probably have to get full admin access eventually, but [that's not very difficult](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/how-reset-password-for-admin-after-migration-from-1-5) if you have access to the files and to the database.

In order to restore your site, there are a couple of things to keep in mind:

- Make sure you have downloaded all the files from the server
- Place the downloaded files in a subfolder of your `www` folder, e.g. `c:\wamp\www\joomla`
- Download the complete database, and restore it to your localhost
- Rename the file `.htaccess` (if present) to something else. It might cause problems if not properly configured.
- Open `configuration.php`, and change the following lines to connect to your database:

  ```
  public $host = 'localhost';
  public $user = 'root';
  public $password = '';
  public $db = 'YOURDATABASENAME';
  ```

  *(On Wamp, the user is root, and the password is empty unless you've made changes to the default configuration)*
- Still in `configuration.php`, set the `tmp` and `log` folder:

  ```
  public $log_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\YOURFOLDER/logs';
  public $tmp_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\YOURFOLDER/tmp';
  ```
- Finally, make sure `$sef_rewrite` is set to `0`:

  ```
  public $sef_rewrite = '0';
  ```

Save, and you should be able to visit your Joomla site by entering `http://localhost/YOURFOLDER` in your browser.